# Moving a view from a viewgroup to another one

Tags: java, android

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="16"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/item_background"
            android:text="Indonesia"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/item_background"
            android:text="English"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly_ll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/item_background"
            android:text="Spain"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/item_background"
            android:text="Brazil"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout llLayout;
    LinearLayout llLayout2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        llLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ly_ll);
        llLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ly_ll2);

        for(int i=0;i<llLayout2.getChildCount();i++){
            View views = llLayout2.getChildAt(i);
            views.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    addedViewTarget(v);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public void addedViewTarget(View view){
        llLayout2.removeView(view);
        llLayout.addView(view);
    }

}
```

I have a case where the case is to move the view from viewgroup to another viewgroup. The problem is when I delete a code **llLayout.addView(view);** it's no problem and the view is successfully erased, but when I want to add a view to llLayout always an error like this "***The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first***". So, I want to move the view in llLayout2 to llLayout when clicked, are you guys the best solution for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oO yes you are right i tried your code and dose not works
 i tried few things and i came up with this weird solution :|

```
 public void addedViewTarget(final View view) {
        ViewGroup vg = ((ViewGroup) view.getParent());
        vg.removeView(view);
        view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                llLayout.addView(view);
            }
        },1000 );

    }
```

i don't know why your code is not working and i dont know why this code is working but I have this hypothesis when you are saying remove View its takes some Time maybe in other thread and when your trying add the view to other ViewGroup instantly it raise error because removing task not complete yet

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(view.getParent()!=null)
    ((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);
llLayout.addView(view);
```

Comment: Previously I've tried it and the result is still error with the same error log. Is there another solution?

Comment: @Renaldi i try this soultion and worked fine for me !

Comment: @AmirHosseinMirzaei I do not know why if the code works when you try, but I've tried it and it does not work the code I delete because it does not work.

Comment: @AmirHosseinMirzaei do you have another solution for this case?